# ESRI phone applications

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-mobile

I have seen sample apps for windows phone, IOS, and even a beta for android. does anyone know if there is anything started for Palm, or Blackberry?
Interested in ArcGIS Server mobile applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Blackberry is supported](http://blogs.esri.com/dev/blogs/arcgisserver/archive/2011/03/02/version-2.2-of-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript-released_2e00_.aspx) through the JavaScript API 2.2.

Last I heard, Palm OS and Web OS is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

For **Blackberry** - yes - using a Third Party

http://www.freeance.com/view/index.php

(Freeance View is compatible with BlackBerry smartphones running BlackBerry OS 4.2.1 or greater. This includes most all BlackBerrys 3 years old or younger, which includes the Bold, Curve, Tour, Torch, Pearl and others.)

Palm - unknown.

Comment: have you used freeance? It looks good but I am a bit sheepish about the additional costs?  It says the viewer is free with no additional costs. Also the supported OS list is a bit old. (.net 2.5) Any comments on all that? Thanks

Comment: A client uses it for real-time mapping - great when has access to wireless/cell network - you can ask for a trial of the software - http://view.freeance.com/gisonblackberry/desktop/form.html - works best with Blackberry Enterprise Server - http://us.blackberry.com/apps-software/business/server/full/